# autocomplete_light is not showing correct suggestions with choice_for_request

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-autocomplete-light

I have `autocomplete-light` in the django `modal form`. I wanted to apply dynamic filtering in the suggestion box, that's why I have used `choice_for_request()` in the `autocompletebasemodel`. But because of using `choice_for_request()`, the suggestions are `not according to the keyword typed` but all the values that can be entered.

This is my form:

```
class CamenuForm(autocomplete_light.ModelForm):
  class Meta:
    model = Ca_dispensaries_item
    exclude = ('dispensary',)
    autocomplete_fields = ('item',)

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.category = kwargs.pop('category', None)
    super(CamenuForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['item'].queryset=Items.objects.filter(product_type__name=self.category)
```

This is the registry and the class:

```
autocomplete_light.register(Items, AutoComplete )
```

class:

```
class AutoComplete(autocomplete_light.AutocompleteModelBase):
    search_fields=('item_name',)
    def choices_for_request(self):
      category = self.request.session.get('category','')
      if category:
        choices = Items.objects.filter(product_type__name=category)
      return self.order_choices(choices)[0:self.limit_choices]
```

I really dont know what changes to make in `changes_for_request` so as to make it work correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through various documents, the solution which worked as correctly as it should be is

```
def choices_for_request(self):
    category = self.request.session.get('category','')
    item=self.request.GET.get('q','')
    choices = self.choices.all()
    if item:
        choices = choices.filter(item_name__icontains=item)
    super(AutoComplete, self).choices_for_request()
    if category:
        choices = choices.filter(product_type__name=category)
    return self.order_choices(choices)[0:self.limit_choices]
```

I missed out

```
item=self.request.GET.get('q','')
```

`autocomplete-light` uses the `get` method and the predefined literal `q` to transfer the value typed by `user`. 
I wasn't able to crack out the meaning of `q`. After some hit and trial, I got that it is used to store the user given value in suggestion box.